# Single word that is used for all home-related services

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for single word that can stand for all home-related services like:

1. Painter
2. Electrician
3. Carpenter
4. Driver
5. Mobile fixer
6. Plasterer
7. Plumber

It may include services that are sometimes performed outside the home.

If possible, please provide a word of just 6–8 characters

Comment: Cheating a bit, but the first three would fit under **home-improvement**. Also, I'm not sure how *driver* is home-related. Otherwise, *hireling* is a general term.

Comment: Simply **home services**, it's common.

Comment: I need a word like "serviceman" because In future I can include services out of home. "home-improvement" and home-services are good words but it will not fit in my condition.

Comment: This is for a programme, isn't it? You're a computer/software developer, aren't you? Whenever I see someone stubbornly rejecting answers with two words, in the end we find out "why". Can you please say "why" this has to be one word, and "why" it has be no longer than 8 letters.

Comment: Yes, I am programmer and and looking for word that is meaningful and a small.

Comment: *Home related all services* **vs** *All home related services*.

Comment: The general term is "construction", and "home construction" is the more specific term.  Except that, if this activity is always on existing homes, then it's "home maintenance".   You're not going to find a 6-character term.

Comment: "worker", "tradesperson", "contractor", or "service provider"? Maybe if you explain more clearly what you want this word for - is it just a variable name in your code, something in a UI, or the name of your business?

Comment: What context would you use the word in? I need to ask because you're saying *services*, but you're actually listing *jobs* (or, depending on the context, abilities/responsibilities). (To be clear, *painting* is the service provided by a *painter*, for example.)

Comment: By "mobile", do you mean "mobile phone"? What does that have to do with a home? People can be homeless and still have cellphones, but more importantly, in my experience, most mobile phone repairs are done at a shop, not a home.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that list of examples, [Handyman](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/handyman) is the first word that came to mind. The 2011 edition of *Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary* has the definition I'm most familiar with which involves small maintenance or repair jobs. The definition from the fifth edition of The *American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language* also calls it a person who does odd jobs* or various small tasks.

The basic idea is that you are appending the suffix [-man](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/-man), which can be found in *Collins English Dictionary – Complete and Unabridged* (1991-2003), to indicate that you're a person with the profession or role of being handy. Handy means being good at [manipulation](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?action=search&word=manipulation&resource=Webster%27s&quicksearch=on) or rather, work with the hand but it is being used primarily in an acquired   sense of being generally useful, as emphasized below:

---

> 3. Ready to the hand; near; also, suited to the use of the hand; convenient; *valuable for reference or use*; as, my tools are handy; a handy volume.
>
> ---
>
> [Webster's Revised Unabridged Dictionary, 1913](http://www.bibliomania.com/2/3/257/frameset.html)

---

The example phrase, "[he's handy around the home](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Handy)" in *Collins Spanish Dictionary - Complete and Unabridged, 8th Edition*, which seems to be an E.S.L. study aid, is actually fairly common in this sense of the word. You might also say someone or something [comes in handy](http://The%20American%20Heritage%C2%AE%20Dictionary%20of%20Idioms%20by%20Christine%20Amme) when it is useful, especially if it is conveniently available, as can be found to The American Heritage Dictionary of Idioms by Christine Amme (1997-2003).

According to the Online Etymology Dictionary, this word [handyman](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=handyman&allowed_in_frame=0) being used for a generally useful person was first recorded in 1843. According to the nGrams chart below, this seems to have only started to gain popularity near the beginning of the 20th century as demonstrated by [Google nGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=handyman%2C%20handyperson&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chandyman%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chandyperson%3B%2Cc0). Handyman certainly *is not* in [Webster's 1844 American Dictionary of the English Language](http://edl.byu.edu/webstersearchresults.php?wq=handyman&x=0&y=0).

Although you may often replace -man with person with varying degrees of success for gender neutrality, this is almost unheard of with handyman, [as the same Googl nGrams chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=handyman%2C%20handyperson&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chandyman%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chandyperson%3B%2Cc0) demonstrates. ([You may see a screenshot of the chart here here, if necessary.](http://postimg.org/image/9e7zbky8d/))

*[Odd job](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/odd+job) isn't technically single word but it's a phrase with special signification that refers to the whole spectrum of nonspecialized and unrelated jobs, especially for domestic or menial work. I suppose this could include driver. The principle idea is that you don't have a *usual* line of work, so you do many odd jobs on the side to suport yourself instead. You could call somebody who performs odd-jobs an odd-jobber. Unfortunately, this option does not refer to the "skill'd trades" like electrician but I figured it's worth mention if you do not want a more gender neutral word because you may call a person who does odd-jobs an odd-jobber, according to the fifth edition of the *American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language*.

The 2011 edition of *Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary* might also call an odd jobber, just a [jobber](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/jobber) but I would not recommend that as the cited dictionary also seems to use several other definitions as well, including a  type of stock-broker, a middleman and as a disparaging word referring to a corrupt and bought out politician.

I would consider picking something else but [thesaurus.com doesn't even list any synonyms for handyman](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/handyman?s=t), aside from jack-of-all-trades which is not even close to a single word and hence will not be discussed. I think handyman may even be the only commonly recognizable word that even can cover all of these bases, without being overly ambiguous.

Comment: Thank you so much for in detail reply But unfortunately I can't use this word. Could you please provide me multiple options so that I can choose one in between?

Comment: @SanjaySoni Ah, that's too bad because like I said at the end I can't.really or at least not for now, except for the others I already suggested. If I do think of any, I shall post another answer. For the sake of other suggesters, you may want to edit the question with the reason this answer can't be used since I don't see why it doesn't fit the present criteria. Also it may help if you add the popular  single-word-request tag to this question while editing it. One last bit of advice is if you award the answer again, you may want to provide the person with an up-vote too, since you can do both.

Comment: In most of the US a "handyman" cannot legally do electrical work on someone else's home.

Comment: That's because you need to be a licensed electrician or plumber to do that type of work in those jurisdictions to keep the house from flooding or burning. However, many people would still call this person a handyman if they have the licensing and offer general services too, in the lexical language. Often, the advice is to ask your handyman if he's licensed to do such work. I'd suggest [contractor](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?action=search&word=contractor&resource=Webster) or [tradesman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tradesman) to @SanjaySoni for that but those are a little too long right now.

Answer (score 1):

A synonym of home-related is domestic. A collective noun for painters, electricians and carpenters, etc. is trade services.
So maybe "domestic trade services"? "Driver" is the odd one out because, by definition, the service is not carried out at the home. A driver would require an adjective of "private" or "personal" or simply "hired".

Answer (score -1):

I like "home services" as a catch-all term for those tasks. But we still need a gender-neutral term for the person who performs them. "Home services technician"?

Comment: 'Home services' is not original, Yam, and you need to show evidence that 'home services technician' is an established term with the correct meaning. I've looked on the internet, and it seems to be used chiefly for people employed by companies to instal and maintain their own-brand white goods etc. // Isn't 'handyman' allowed nowadays, on PC grounds? 'Handyperson' sounds awful.